Power method and numerical analysis
Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{{n}*{n}}$ be a symmetric  matrix with eigenvalues satifying $|\lambda_{1}|>|\lambda_{2}|\ge\ldots \ge|\lambda_{n-1}|>|\lambda_{n}|$ and corresponding eigenvectors $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$.(normailzed with unit Euclidean norm)
a)Given an initial vector $v_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, recall power method algorithm applied to the matrix $A-\mu I$ with shift $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ to generate a sequence of vectors $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots, v_{k}\ldots$
b)Give conditions on $v_{0}$ and $\mu$ such that $v_{k}$ converges to $\mp x_{ 1}$ as $\lim_{k\to\infty}$.
c) Show that  the convergence of the power method is the fastest for $\mu=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{n})$.What is the rate of convergence in this case?
What I wrote was $y_{1}=(A-\mu I)x_{0}=$ and $x_{1}=\frac{y_{1}}{||y_{1}||}$.This should be the power iteration. In addition to satify statement  the eigenvectors must be linearly independent and $|\mu-\lambda_{1}|>|\mu-\lambda_{2}|>\ldots >|\mu-\lambda_{n}|$ must be satisfied. Moreover $v_{0}$ should not be in $ker{(A-\mu\mathbb{I}})^{k}$ for any $k$ because we should not have zeros . I checked very similar result from the video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cs2M7GLvOhA&list=PLOzRYVm0a65d0WWST6wvOP6m7VRQyRgSa&index=27 it is informative about the case in which there exists no shift. In my opinion the logic will not be different but I could not get the last part. If you help I will really be plased.

You might want to consider a basis in which $A$ is diagonal.

why is it so?Why do I need a basis?

You need to do some work. What would the power iteration "look like" if $A$ was diagonal?

Do you write for part b or c?

Actually, I didn't pay attention, but the result is certainly not true as stated. You are missing some sign information, such as all eigenvalues non negative or that the absolute values are sorted.

Hello, is my result about sorting wrong? Could you write your idea and proof?

why did you close this question?

I didn't close the question.

Can you fix the question please, otherwise it may get closed again.

What do you mean by fixing the question?

Did you read my comments?

This is not my fault not my question!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

this was PhD qualification exam question but that was in the old way. I just retyped it. Now I wrote not as the actual

I'm confused, the question was added from your account. How is it not your question?

That is qualifying exam question I did not write this but the Professors wrote this. Therefore I trusted them and asked it on the website

Your matrix can be diagonalized, hence your problem can be reduced to case where the matrix is diagonal. What progress have you made on this front? The video is almost 40 minutes long, so your reference to "... the last part" is too vague to be helpful .You need to specify exactly what is unclear.

Thank you what is unclear is I can not understand well if my conditions are enough or I can not be sure about all the conditions on part b and part c is very unclear I do not get it. I only know that the ration$\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda{1}}$ must be small in the case where shift does not exist

The question is a bit vague for Part c). It is not true that the convergence is necessarily fastest for the $\mu$ given above. Take a diagonal matrix with entries $-1,3,4$. Then the above gives a rate of ${2 \over 3}$, whereas $\mu=3$ gives a rate of ${1 \over 4}$. Presumably the intent of the question is to find (assuming it exists) the fastest rate such that $v_k$ converges to $\pm x_1$.

Unless you add your own partial analysis of the problem it is impossible to give you exactly what you need to finish the problem on your own.

Note that the symmetry of $A$ provides you with an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Note also that the order of the absolute value of the eigenvalues changes as you change the shift. Hence your statement about the absolute values cannot be true in general.

I suspect that the hypotheses should be $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_k|$ for all $k$ and $\lambda_2 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n$.

That is one possibility. I think that good problem can be made when the two extreme eigenvalues are distinct, i.e., $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 \leq \dotsc \leq \lambda_{n-1} < \lambda_n$. Using a suitable shift we can promote either the left end or the right end of the spectrum. If we focus on $\lambda_1$, then we want $\mu$ such that $|\lambda_2 - \mu| = |\lambda_n - \mu|$. Conversely, if we focus on $\lambda_n$, then we want $\mu$ such that $|\lambda_1- \mu| = |\lambda_{n-1}-\mu|$.

I added an answer under slightly modified hypotheses. I definitely would not have worked this out in orals.

Would you comment on my answer so that I can improve it? As you can see, I have addressed the original problem without extra assumptions that were made along the way.

Here is a proof of Part c) with the hypotheses: $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_k|$ for $k =2,...,n$ and $\lambda_n \le \cdots \le \lambda_2$.
To simplify the proof, also assume that $\lambda_n \le \cdots \le \lambda_2< \lambda_1$ (note that this implies $\lambda_1 > 0$). The goal is to find a shift $\mu$ (assuming it exists) that gives the fastest rate of convergence and $\lambda_1 -\mu$ is still the dominant eigenvalue.
That is, we only consider $\mu$ such that $|\lambda_1-\mu| > |\lambda_k-\mu|$ $k =2,...,n$, or equivalently, $|\lambda_1-\mu| > \max_{k =2,...,n} |\lambda_k-\mu|$. Note that for such values of $\mu$, $\max_{k =2,...,n} |\lambda_k-\mu|$ is the second most dominant eigenvalue.
A key fact here is $\max_{k =2,...,n} |\lambda_k-\mu| = \max(\mu-\lambda_n, \lambda_2-\mu)$.
Using this fact it is straightforward to check that $|\lambda_1-\mu| > |\lambda_k-\mu|$ $k =2,...,n$ iff $\mu < {1 \over 2} (\lambda_n+\lambda_1)$ (which is $< \lambda_1$), and so
we wish to minimise the ratio of the second most dominant eigenvalue to the most dominant,
$f(\mu) = {\max(\mu-\lambda_n, \lambda_2-\mu) \over \lambda_1 - \mu}$ over the domain $\mu < {1 \over 2} (\lambda_n+\lambda_1)$.
Letting
$f_1(\mu) = {\mu-\lambda_n \over \lambda_1 - \mu}$, $f_2(\mu) = {\lambda_2-\mu \over \lambda_1 - \mu}$ we have $f(\mu) = \max(f_1(\mu),f_2(\mu))$ and $f'_1(\mu) = {\lambda_1-\lambda_n \over (\lambda_1 - \mu)^2}> 0$ and $f'_2(\mu) = {\lambda_2-\lambda_1 \over (\lambda_1 - \mu)^2 } < 0$.
Letting $\mu^* = {1 \over 2} (\lambda_n+\lambda_2)$ we see that $f$ is decreasing for $\mu<\mu^*$ and increasing for $\mu> \mu^*$, in particular, $f$ has a $\min$ at $\mu^*$ (on the domain $(-\infty, {1 \over 2} (\lambda_n+\lambda_1))$).
Substituting gives the optimal rate ${{{\lambda_2-\lambda_n} \over 2} \over \lambda_1 - {{\lambda_2+\lambda_n} \over 2}}$.
If instead $\lambda_1 < \lambda_n \le \cdots \le \lambda_2$, then consider the power method applied to $-A$ which has eigenvalues
$-\lambda_2 \le \cdots \le -\lambda_n < -\lambda_1$, which would result in a shift (of $-A$) of $-{1 \over 2} (\lambda_n+\lambda_2)$
and a rate of $-{{{\lambda_2-\lambda_n} \over 2} \over \lambda_1 - {{\lambda_2+\lambda_n} \over 2}}$. Hence the corresponding shift to $A$ would be $\mu^*$ and, in general, the rate given by
$\left | {{{\lambda_2-\lambda_n} \over 2} \over \lambda_1 - {{\lambda_2+\lambda_n} \over 2}} \right| $.

why is it straightforward to check that $|\lambda_{1}-\mu|>|\lambda_{k}-\mu|$ for $k=2,,,\ldots n$ iff  $\mu<\frac{1}{2}(\lambda_{n}+\lambda_{1})$

Use the key fact. Drawing a little picture will help.

I elaborated slightly, hopefully that helps.

This is a problem that presents several features of interest. In particular, the scheme itself delightfully simple and easy to implement and a shift is often used in combination with inversion rather than matrix multiplication.
The question mutated after it was by posed by addition of unnecessary conditions. In this answer I address the original question. The eigenvalues are spread out over the real line and the two right-most eigenvalues are distinct.
Formally, we are given a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Let $\{\lambda_j\}_{j=1}^m$ denote the $m$ eigenvalues of $A$. We assume that the eigenvalues numbered such that $$\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \dotsc \leq \lambda_m.$$ We assume that there is a gap between the two right-most eigenvalues $\lambda_{m-1}$ and $\lambda_m$, i.e.,
$$ \lambda_{m-1} < \lambda_m.$$
Our objective is find a real shift $\mu$ that accentuates the gap between the eigenvalues $\lambda_{m}-\mu$ and $\lambda_j - \mu$ for all $j < m$. Specifically, we seek $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda_m - \mu$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $A - \mu I$, i.e.,
$$ \forall j < m \: : \: |\lambda_j - \mu| < |\lambda_m - \mu|$$ and such that the fraction
$$ f(\mu) = \frac{\max\{|\lambda_j - \mu| \: : \: j < m\}}{|\lambda_m - \mu|}$$
is as small as possible.
It is clear that there is a shift $\mu_0$ such that $\lambda_1 - \mu_0$ and $\lambda_{m-1} - \mu_0$ straddle zero perfectly in the sense that
$$ a = \lambda_1 - \mu_0 < 0 < \lambda_{m-1} - \mu_0 = b$$ and
$$ b = -a$$ Indeed, this shift is given by $$\mu_0 = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_{m-1}}{2}.$$ We claim that this is the optimal value of the shift $\mu$. Let us first demonstrate that the shift is actually useful. Suppose that $m = 3$ and that $$(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3) = (9, 11, 12).$$
In this case, the standard power method will converge, because $$9 \leq 11 < 12$$ but the convergence rate will be the paltry value $\rho = \frac{11}{12}$. The suggested shift is $\mu_0 = \frac{9 + 11}{2} = 10$ and
$$(\lambda_1-\mu_0, \lambda_2-\mu_0, \lambda_3-\mu_0) = (-1, 1, 2).$$ The new convergence rate will be $\rho = \frac{1}{2}$, a rather respectable value. But is this the smallest possible value?
Let us return to the general case and show that $$0 < f(\mu_0) \leq f(\mu)$$ for all $\mu$. We shall consider the twin cases of $\mu < \mu_0$ and $\mu > \mu_0$.

If $\mu < \mu_0$, then $$f(\mu) = \frac{\lambda_{m-1} - \mu}{\lambda_m - \mu}.$$ This is a strictly decreasing function of $\mu$, hence $$f(\mu_0) < f(\mu)$$ for all $\mu < \mu_0$.
If $\mu > \mu_0$, then we need to tread carefully. If $\mu$ is too large, then $\lambda_m - \mu$ ceases to be the dominant eigenvalue and the power method becomes useless to us. This happens when $\lambda_1 - \mu$ and $\lambda_m - \mu$ straddles $0$ perfectly in the sense that $$\lambda_m - \mu = -(\lambda_1 - \mu)$$ or equivalently when $$\mu = \mu^*:= \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_m}{2}.$$ In short, we have to limit ourselves to $$\mu_0 < \mu < \mu^*.$$ For such $\mu$, the dominant eigenvalue is still $\lambda_m - \mu$, but the second most dominant eigenvalue is $\lambda_1 - \mu$ and $$f(\mu) = \frac{|\lambda_1 - \mu|}{|\lambda_m - \mu|} = -\frac{\lambda_1 - \mu}{\lambda_m - \mu}.$$ It is easy to see that this is a strictly increasing function of $\mu$, hence $$f(\mu_0) < f(\mu)$$ for all $\mu \in (\mu_0,\mu^*)$.


While it is implicit, it might help the reader to explicitly assume that $\lambda_m$ is strictly dominant in addition to specifying the ordering.

@copper.hat I am not convinced that the extra assumption is helpful, we will simply have to test it with a live audience. Regardless, it is not necessary to assume that $\lambda_m$ is dominant because the shift $\mu_0$ ensures that $\lambda_m - \mu_0$ is dominant regardless of $\lambda_m$ original status. In particular, if $$(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3) = (-91,-89,-88),$$ then $\lambda_3$ is not dominant, but $\mu_0 = \frac{-91-89}{2}  = -90$ shifts the spectrum back to $(-1,1,2)$. I think what is missing is a drawing of a real line with some well placed eigenvalues.

I see what you are doing. In that case there is a slight disconnect (apart from a notational one) with the OP's question.
